# How to get a specific line based on a pattern if found

Tags: sed, awk

I am trying to gather the filenames from a very big file depending on if a particular user, in this case `windowsdom\nasarchive` is found.

I tried running `sed -nr "/-{3,}/h; /Path\s*:/H; /windowsdom\\nasarchive\s+Allow\s+FullControl/{x;G;p}" logfilename` but it does not bring anything.

```
-----------------------
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - April 21 - 2.doc


AccessToString : windowsdom\nasarchive Allow  FullControl
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                 BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize

-----------------------
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2009\Credit status - Sept. 23 - 59.doc


AccessToString : windowsdom\acl_1 Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                 windowsdom\acl_2 Allow  Modify, Synchronize
                 windowsdom\acl_3 Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                 windowsdom\adm_server Allow  Modify, Synchronize
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl


-----------------------
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - August 10 - 3.doc


AccessToString : windowsdom\nasarchive Allow  FullControl
                 BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                 BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize



-----------------------
```

Expected result:

```
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - April 21 - 2.doc
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - August 10 - 3.doc
```

Can someone think how to get the expected result?

Comment: +1 for reasonable sample data, expected output AND an attempt to solved the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I had to rewrite my answer, so you might want to check if you feel it should remain accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I know it's not the best idea to edit an accepted answer, but it was substantially inaccurate. It turns out that the hold space is retained between lines.

The main problem with your command is that you are using double quotes, so the escaped backslash is seen unescaped by `sed`. Change them to single quotes and it starts working:

```
$ sed -nr '/-{3,}/h; /Path\s*:/H; /windowsdom\\nasarchive\s+Allow\s+FullControl/{x;G;p}' file
-----------------------
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - April 21 - 2.doc
AccessToString : windowsdom\nasarchive Allow  FullControl
-----------------------
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - August 10 - 3.doc
AccessToString : windowsdom\nasarchive Allow  FullControl
```

Now, you can simplify it to match the desired output. What you'll eventually get is shown in protong's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20588991/1258041):

```
sed -rn '/^Path:/h;/windowsdom\\nasarchive\s+Allow\s+FullControl/{g;p}' file
```

POSIX alternative:

```
$ sed --posix -n '/^Path:/h;/windowsdom\\nasarchive[[:space:]]\{1,\}Allow[[:space:]]\{1,\}FullControl/{g;p}' log.txt
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - April 21 - 2.doc
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - August 10 - 3.doc
```

Comment: @dawg Sure, but the OP is using features specific to the GNU version anyway. Also, added a POSIX-compatible version.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^Path:/h;/windowsdom\\nasarchive\s+Allow\s+FullControl/{g;p}' file
```

This prints the last `Path` string when it encounters the required string.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). You can save each line with the `path` and print it when found a line which first field matches `AccessToString` and the third one matches `windowsdom\nasarchive`:

```
awk '
    $1 ~ /^Path/ { path = $0; next } 
    $1 ~ /^AccessToString/ && $3 ~ /^windowsdom\\nasarchive$/ { print path }
' infile
```

It yields;:

```
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - April 21 - 2.doc
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - August 10 - 3.doc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `gawk`<sup>1</sup> you can define a record as the text between lines of dashes with `RS="-----------------------"` and each field to be a line by setting `FS="\n"`:

```
gawk '
   BEGIN {RS="-----------------------"; FS="\n"} 
   $5 ~ /windowsdom\\nasarchive\s+Allow\s+FullControl/ {print $2;}
' ur_file.txt
```

Prints:

```
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - April 21 - 2.doc
Path: U:\Credit share\BI-WEEKLY CREDIT NOTES\2010\Credit status - August 10 - 3.doc
```

---

<sup>1</sup>To find out the version of awk, use `awk --version`. It is typical for linux to have `gawk` and have that linked to `awk`. OS X does not have `gawk` but it is easily installed.